# SSH script password input

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

So I am running Linux Mint 17.2.  I have a bash file I would like to run in terminal to login via SSH into my other mint 17.2 server.  I am able to do this manually no problem, but when I try using the following script, it attempts to connect to the server, but then it just sits there at the password prompt.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh mediaserver@mediaserver
expect "pasword:"
send "password\r"
```

not sure what to do here.  Online help gets me no where so far.

Comment: you should use ssh keys instead of passwords. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response from ssh command using expect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389694/how-to-get-response-from-ssh-command-using-expect)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called `sshpass` that does what you want.

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Once it's installed, you can put into your script the following:

```
sshpass -p 'password-here' ssh mediaserver@mediaserver
```

Of course, it's generally not good practice to put a plain text password into a script or into source code.  That said, this does exactly what you are asking.